# detect when application using permissions ~ Android

Tags: root-access, permissions

I list all permissions of the new installed application on rooted Android device. But I want to detect when an application uses these permission. For example, I installed an app and it uses READ_CALENDAR permission. It is not always read my calendar data. I want to detect the time it reads my calendar data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible. How to realize it, depends on the Android version used: For Android 4.0 and earlier, the IMHO best solution is installing [LBE Privacy Guard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lbe-privacy-guard/com.lbe.security.lite), which you can configure to issue a popup whenever a given permission was requested (so you can decide whether to permit or deny access). However, do not attempt installing this on Android 4.1+, or you'll end up in a [boot-loop](/questions/tagged/boot-loop); the XDA Developers have "localized versions" of [LBE Security Master](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lbe%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8%E5%A4%A7%E5%B8%88%EF%BC%88%E5%85%8Droot%EF%BC%89/com.lbe.security) available instead (a version I find bloated, as it tries to cover to much things).

Apart from these two, I know of no other app informing you of an access at the time it's made (which does not mean there aren't any). Other tools might however log access so you can either see the log entry afterwards, or at least know whether an app has used that permission at all (e.g. [XPrivacy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/xprivacy-installer/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer)). I'm not sure how [PDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pdroid-privacy-protection/com.privacy.pdroid) handles this, as I've never used it.

Comment: Actually I asked this question to detect permission time on my program. I wont use other programs. I should write it in my program.. Thank u ,, at least I know this is possible. :)

Comment: Well, that makes your question off-topic here then. If you're after an implementation to your own code, you should rather take your question to [SO], as our site here is for *end-users*.

Comment: ohh ok I dont realize that site is for end-user..Thank u for warning. I also asked there this question and I take an answer 'it is not possible'.. anyway this helped me..

Comment: Glad I was able to help. You might want to mark the answer as "accepted" if you consider it a solution from an end-users point of view (as we do not deal with development stuff, that's the part we care for here), so the question shows up in searches as having a solution. Just tick the check-mark next to the question to do so. Thanks!